# Can Jersey convert a GET returned POJO to XML or JSON depending on the request's Accept header?

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jersey

This question is for Jersey 2.x.

Let's say I have a GET method. The client request contains an Accept header for either XML or JSON.  Is it possible for the method to return a POJO in the representation the client requested?

Currently, my GET method returns JSON using Jackson.  But I don't know how to make it return XML when the client requests it.  All the examples I see here expect the POJO to be JAXB annotated.

The POJO being returned doesn't have JAXB annotations and I'm not allowed to add them.  But the object does fulfill the JavaBean contract, so it's a real POJO.

Since Jackson can serialize a POJO (with no annotations) to JSON , I hope there's an existing MessageBodyWriter that does the same for XML.

If this is possible:
- How do I annotate the GET method?  Currently, I use the line below.  Is this enough?

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
```

- I'm configuring Jersey through web.xml and Maven.  I've got JSON serialization working, but I haven't figured out how to configure for XML output.  What config is needed to make XML work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what do you want to do if the header has, let's say, `Accept: application/json;q=0.8,text/xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes that is possible here a small example:

```
@Path("/recipe")
public class RecipeResource {
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<Recipe> getRecipesBrowser() {
    System.out.println("REST Service Method getRecipesBrowser called");
    System.out.println("Called URI: " + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Recipe> dummyData = new ArrayList<>();
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(1), "Recipe1", "Description1", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(2), "Recipe2", "Description2", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(3), "Recipe3", "Description3", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(4), "Recipe4", "Description4", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(5), "Recipe5", "Description5", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(6), "Recipe6", "Description6", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(7), "Recipe7", "Description7", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(8), "Recipe8", "Description8", null));
    dummyData.add(new Recipe(new Long(9), "Recipe9", "Description9", null));

    return dummyData;
}
```

}

POJO for Recipe needs the Annotation @XMlRootElement:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Recipe {

private Long recipeId;

private String name;

private String description;

private List<Fixing> fixings;

public Recipe() {

}

public Recipe(Long id, String name, String description, List<Fixing> fixings) {
    super();
    this.recipeId = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.fixings = fixings;
}

public Long getRecipeId() {
    return recipeId;
}

public void setRecipeId(Long id) {
    this.recipeId = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public List<Fixing> getFixings() {
    return fixings;
}

public void setFixings(List<Fixing> fixings) {
    this.fixings = fixings;
}
```

}

Then you will get in your Browser XML and when using a REST Client JSON:

In Chrome requesting the URL

```
 http://test:8080/YourService/rest/recipe
```

The Chrome Request Headers are:

```
GET /YourService/rest/recipe HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

In the Advanced REST Client the Request Headers are:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: beaker.session.id=f1f5577e0dd2047968a2ada05acc1952; nas_lang=ENG
```

The difference is the Request Header Accept. the browser sets it to 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml

The REST Client sets it to
Accept: */*

So with this parameter you can influence if xou receive JSON or XML as response.